# How to prepare chemically paint stripped wall before repainting?

Tags: repainting

The attached picture below is my wall after I paint stripped it: I would apply the paint stripper on the surface, let it act for the required amount of time and then I would scrape - I've repeated this 3 times on the same wall to achieve the result as in the picture.

[image]

I have a few questions please :

1. Visually, is the wall clean enough now paint-wise for me to continue to the next step or do I need to reapply the stripper again and give it more scraping?
2. Before I repaint the wall, what are the advised steps I should do to prep the wall before I can paint on it? I assume I would need to do something to make sure the paint stripper chemicals are off the wall like sanding or cleaning with water or spirits?

Many thanks!

Comment: 1) It's your decision whether the base is clean enough or not. 2) After scraping, always clean the surface with warm water until all residuals are wiped clean. I would at least let it dry overnight to apply the primer and see whether it stays or not. A light sanding may help before paint.

Comment: Thanks. 1) Would a professional consider that clean/good enough?

Comment: Primer, with or without a skim coat for smoothness. Your call.

Comment: @JACK your comment is exactly the answer I was going to type up. Why not make an actual answer out of that.

Comment: Thank you so much, do I need to do anything to remove the paint stripper residues before applying the primer like some sanding or wiping?

Comment: We can't possibly know without knowing ***your reasons*** for paint stripping.  It's not something everybody just does all the time.  Have you removed all the layers of paint that were delaminating?  Have you removed the lead paint you were after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go over the paint stripper directions. They will tell you what's needed to remove any stripper residue. Then a good primer based on the type of paint you'll be using for the final coat. I have always used a pole sander and give the wall a quick sanding just to remove any rough edges left from scraping or taping. Once the primer dries, you'll get a good idea on how smooth the wall is and whether or not it's ready for your final coat.

Comment: Thanks Jack, sorry, what do you mean by going over the paint stripper directions?

Comment: @ld_pvl  Read the directions on the label of the paint stripper you used. They always include how to apply it, how to scrap it off and then how to clean, remove the residue.

Comment: Ah silly me! It says wipe surface using white spirit or methylated spirit. After that rub with sandpaper. Thanks!

Comment: @ld_pvl  You learn something new every day on this site...